# The wrong Twitter account is showing in Google SERPs when searching for my name

Tags: google, search-results

If you search for me by name on Google, the wrong Twitter page has started to show in SERPs. [Check here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Scott+Helme#q=Scott+Helme). The offending Twitter page usually comes up about 10th in the results.

My Twitter page is linked from my blog and my Google+ profile so I don't understand how this account is starting to rank more highly than my own, given the links to my site which is the top result.

My question is, is there a way to prevent this? What options do I have to either boost my own Twitter page up the rankings or try to remove/reduce the rank of the other page when searching.

Comment: Off topic I like your tweets! and I think I'll follow you ;) but! may I request you get a 2560x1600 background for us big screeners :P  take a look http://i.imgur.com/SPdqZ8B.jpg ;)

Comment: Holy smokes, that is some serious resolution! Image updated, how does it look now?

Comment: Works superb ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google prevents too many similar results returned in the serps this could be one of the factors here but its likely because you don't have enough links actually to the twitter account. Google can associate whats relevant to you and what's not... Now Google will be aware that the 10th result is not your tweeter account, Google is attempting to give users multiple choices as well a serps with a full page of you, and no other Scott Helme would crappy for everyone else.

This isn't to say it can't be done but simply linking from the top position to another site doesn't always have the desired effect othersite shoe-companyA.com links to shoe-companyB.com and so on and then you would have shoe-companyA > D in the results.

The problem here is your expecting your site to pass all the SEO heavenly the love when its more complex than that and Google will need a lot more to give you that position. Take celebs for example, they have tweeter links all over and followers is also a factor... well some believe.

Also Google has the ability to know what self-created content is, so if you've created many profiles all linking to your tweeter account you'd hope that this would bump it up, it helps but it won't be a major factor since it knows they are profile links. My advice, more followers and more on the page inner content links to your actual twitter account. People with top rankings twitter accounts will often have hundreds of links from real content on other sites, not profiles, not citations company links or about.me links etc. Guest blogging is considered one of the best methods of ranking a twitter account since most sites excellent sites don't allow site promotion within the article your written but will often allow a twitter author attachment.

Comment: Additionally if you was the only Scott Helme you wouldn't be experiencing this issue. Are you the most important Scott Helme? Google needs convincing. Simple ;)